# Middle Man Server HTTPS/SSL

Tags: .net, encryption, ssl, https

I am working on a project that uses a Microsoft .NET server that is to perform changes to HTTPS/SSL data.  For example, client machine using a browser calls server B via HTTPS/SSL that in turns forwards the request to server C, again HTTPS/SSL.  The response is to be sent back to the client machine via server B from server C, however server B is to wrap some data into the response before sending it back.

I am assuming as the response is encrypted, server B will have to unencrypt the response, change the data, encrypt the data and send the response.

Does this sound possible on a .NET middle server?  Will there be any issue with keys?

Comment: This is known as Man-In the-Middle Attack. It sounds possible with a .NET server. There should not be an issue with keys, especially if the client knows (and accepts) that Server B is between it and Server C.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can update your own question by editing it. You can vote for questions (upvote or downvote) and if you get the answer that satisfies your needs and answers your question, you can mark it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends whether you can make the client trust your certificate that you use in the middle server. If you can (eg. you control the clients), then there's no problem - create a new self-signed certificate that will have target server's host name and other attributes of valid SSL certificate for that target host, put it to trusted root storage on the client and make the middle server either intercept the traffic or just direct the client's traffic via your middle server.

In other cases such change is impossible. I.e. the key is making a certificate trusted.

Comment: Just a note, this is exactly how [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp) intercepts and decrypts HTTPS traffic on the wire.